# WebRequest The request was aborted, The request was cancelled

Tags: c#, rest, webrequest, script-task, ssis-2017

[EDIT] my mistake - showed the wrong line on which the error occured.

I'm SQL Server developer not a .net developer so bear with me please.

Consuming a 3rd party Rest API using a Script Task in SSIS (Visual Studio 2017) and getting the following error

> The request was aborted, The request was cancelled.

This is the code I'm using

```
    string responseMessage = null;
    string pushResponse = null;

    try
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(post_url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        req.Timeout = 600000;
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(api_username, api_password);
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\r\n\"carCountryCode\": \"" + api_countryCode + "\",\r\n\"carLicenseNumber\": \"" + carLicenseNumber + "\",\r\n\"client\": \"" + api_client + "\"\r\n}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }


        if (req != null)
        {
            var response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream);

                    responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    pushResponse = responseMessage;
                    reader.Close();
                    responseStream.Close();
                    response.Close();
                }
                responseStream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                responseMessage = response.StatusDescription;
                //MessageBox.Show("Error:" + responseMessage);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("Success: " + pushResponse);
            response.Close();
        }

    }
    //catch (Exception e)
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ERROR", ex.Message, null, 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
```

The error is generated on line - [EDIT] my mistake, showed the wrong line before

```
var response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

This was working until about this morning.
I've checked and the service is up and running.

Comment: What are the purpose of using \r\n in your json?

Comment: following the 3rd party documentation

Comment: Add req.contentlengh to your request and req version to http 1.1

Comment: req.Content.Length to the length of the json string?  and req.version doesn't appear

Comment: Yes json content length and that other one is protocol version

Comment: Version or protocol version isn;t a property of Webrequest  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: its seems to be an issue with KeepAlive I think.  I've raised another question

Answer (score 0):

What we need to do is to edit this file and override the inherited GetWebRequest method. The overriding method should look something like this (sample written in C#):

```
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);

        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        return webRequest;
    }
```

remember that when you do an Update Web Reference command, VS will regenerate the file and your changes will be lost. So you will need to override the method again after each update.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a silly question, but if it was working and suddenly stopped... did you check if the service is still available? Use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to check.

Comment: I did, the service is up and running

Comment: Did you try to turn off Windows firewall?